# Easiest way to upload notes from Blackberry (8520) phone to Windows?

Tags: blackberry

I find it faster to type notes with the hardware keyboard of my old [Blackberry 8520](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BlackBerry_Curve_8520) than the Android smartphone that I use otherwise.

As an alternative to installing the 100MB BlackBerry Desktop Manager application, I notice that the 8520 can take a MicroSD card: Is there an easy way to copy notes to the MicroSD card before moving it to a Windows host? Are notes just plain text files that can be copied to Windows through USB with PTP/MTP?

FWIW, the phone is running the 4.6.1.314 version of the OS.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you e-mail it to Android? BlackBerry are dying... They have fast ways to type on Android. Have you heard of Swype?

Comment: Thanks. I'll give Swype a try and see how it goes. It doesn't matter if Blackberry is dying, though, if I only use my old phone once in a while to type stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Try [BBNotePad](http://krzysztow.com/BBNotePad/). It is free.

BBNotePad is a plain text editor that allows you to write full-length documents or even code wherever you might be. BBNotePad sports three text sizes and it saves files as .txt files that can be opened directly on any computer, saving to either your BlackBerry's internal memory or on your removable flash card. It's very useful for sending notes and memos over Bluetooth to other handheld devices.

For your computer, you'd need a MicroSD card reader, or a bluetooth transceiver if you wanted to transmit the text file wirelessly.

[image: BBNotePad Image]